# Local Notifications don't show neither in emulator nor my physical Android phone

Tags: android, flutter, notifications

I searched online for a simple tutorial/example for producing Local Notifications in Android using Flutter SDK and the simplest one I could find is this:

Main function code (which is actually just a single button that produces a notification when pressed):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:webserver/noti.dart';

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    Noti.initialize(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [Color(0xFF3ac3cb), Color(0xFFf85187)])),
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),

          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
              ),
              width: 200,
              height: 80,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){

                  Noti.showBigTextNotification(title: "New message title", body: "Your long body", fln: flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);
                }, child: Text("click"),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

and the code of a seperate .dart file imported to main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class Noti{
  static Future initialize(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) async {
    var androidInitialize = const AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iOSInitialize = const IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationsSettings = InitializationSettings(android: androidInitialize,
        iOS: iOSInitialize);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationsSettings );
  }

  static Future showBigTextNotification({var id =0,required String title, required String body,
    var payload, required FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin fln
  } ) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'you_can_name_it_whatever1',
      'channel_name',

      playSound: true,
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );

    var not= NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
        iOS: const IOSNotificationDetails()
    );
    await fln.show(0, title, body,not );
  }

}
```

When I press the button I get:

> E/flutter ( 2807): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
> (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7) E/flutter (
> 2807): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296:18) E/flutter
> ( 2807):  E/flutter ( 2807): #2
> FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show
> (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:215:7)
> E/flutter ( 2807):  E/flutter ( 2807): #3
> Noti.showBigTextNotification (package:webserver/noti.dart:29:5)
> E/flutter ( 2807):  E/flutter ( 2807):

I tried it on an emulator (Pixel 5 API 30), and then to my physical Android phone (Android 11, MIUI 12.5.14) with no success.

In app build.gradle I've added:

> compileSdkVersion 33

I have no idea how to move on. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. I use Windows 10 and VSCode. When I press a button I get output `D/EGL_emulation(10230): app_time_stats: avg=2032.19ms min=1067.15ms max=2997.24ms count=2`

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this by enabling **notifications** of app on the **emulator's settings**.

- In your Emulator go to:

> Settings -> Notifications -> App Notifications

- Toggle the switch on. ( if you cannot find your app select "All Apps" on the drop downs).
- Go to Notification History in your Emulators Notification settings and toggle the switch on.

Answer (score -1):

How about you try using an android emulator with an API version that matches the minimum 'compileSdkVersion' first? In this case, upgrading your emulator's android version from 30 to flutter_local_notifications's minimum version of 33.